# Django: Where to clean values from URL?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I want to write a class based view, and I want to clean a part of the URL:

The URL looks like this:

```
r'^some-date/(?P<date>\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)/view'
```

Which method should I use to "clean" the string (for example "2018-12-31") to the python datetime object?

Comment: which django version are you using ?

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBatta at the moment I still use an old version, but sooner or later I will use Django 2.0. I am very happy that the new version has path converters. On older Django versions I can help myself. Thank you for asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In django2.0 we can use path converters.

> custom_path_converter.py

```
from datetime import datetime

class DatePathConverter:
    regex = '\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d'
 
    def to_python(self, date_str):
        date = datetime.strptime(value, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
        return date
 
    def to_url(self, date):
        return date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

> urls.py

```
from django.urls import register_converter, path
from .views import views
register_converter(DatePathConverter, 'date')
 
urlpatterns = [
    # ....
    path('some-date/<date:date>/', views.some_view)
    # ....
]
```

Read: https://learnbatta.com/blog/django-custom-path-converters-17/
Official-doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#registering-custom-path-converters

Comment: First link is broken :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def clean_date(request, date):
    datetime_object = datetime.strptime(date, '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
```